# Changing the Bar Colors in MS Candle Stick Chart

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, candlestick-chart

I have got an MS chart that I am showing in an ASP.net page.

The type of the series that I am attaching to the chart is of CandleStick

How can I change the colors of the bars from default blue and white to something else eg Red and Green?

I haven't found any properties so far.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// setting bar colors
this._chart.Series[0]["PriceUpColor"] = "Green"; 
this._chart.Series[0]["PriceDownColor"] = "Red";
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Red, PriceUpColor=Green";
```